# Views taxonomy page with child terms only

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

i use this view configuration to get child terms from my taxonomy-vocabular.

[image]

i used the depth of 1. This give me the term id + its first child term content. But how i can get the child terms only?

Example:

Chef

--Subchef

----Child 1

----Child 2

When i click on Subchef it shows me Content from "Subchef" and from Child 1 and from Child 2. But i dont want to show the Subchef content. Any solution for this?

Comment: no solution with views?

Comment: it must be possible? Maybe with php filteR?